# How to Use Encrypted password in autoinstall.yml - late command

Tags: password, encryption, autoinstall

Hi There is a requirement, I have kept a password protected archive file in the filesystem of an ISO by using Squashfs tool. I want to untar it at time of ISO installation.

Is there a way to provide encrypted password with command in the late command section of autoinstall.yml ??

Please Help...